# Compact Hausdorff space with distinct points $x,y$ implies existence of continuous real function $f$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact, Hausdorff space, then I want to show there $\exists$ a continuous real valued function $f$ on $X$, such that for distinct $x,y \in X$, $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

---

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, for distinct $x,y\in X$, I know their neighborhoods $U_x, V_y$, $U_x\cap V_y =\phi$. And It seems the compactness is crucial for proving the existence of continuous function $f$, but I am not sure where the compactness appears.

Comment: You may be interested in [Urysohn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 2):

$X$ compact Hausdorff implies $X$ is normal.

$\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are disjoint closed sets.

Urysohn's lemma does the rest.