# Does compact Hausdorff space with many distinct points produces continuous real valued function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

In the previous posts, I ask the existence of a continuous real-valued function on compact Hausdorff space which gives two distinct points in $X$ gives different values.

[Compact Hausdorff space with distinct points $x,y$ implies existence of continuous real function $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202125/compact-hausdorff-space-with-distinct-points-x-y-implies-existence-of-continuo/4202336#4202336)

Now I want to extend this more than two points. For examples

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausodrff space and $x_i \in X$ be distints points in $X$. Then is there a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_i) \neq f(x_j)$? [Let simply just define $f(x_i) =i$]

It seems since $X$ is normal, $n=2$ two points are okay. How about $n=3, 4,? $ or infinitely many points?

Comment: What did you try? At least for finite case, it's still Uryshon lemma...

Comment: @ArcticChar, How about the infinite case? Can we still use Uryshon lemma?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Take a look at the statement of the lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is compact, then every injective continuous map from $X$ into $\Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $f(X)$. So, if it turns out that $X$ is *not* homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb R$ (such as when $X=S^1$), then the answer is negative.

In the finite case, it is true, by Urysohn's lemma, as you were told in the comments.

Comment: "every continuous map from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism" you are confusing me

Comment: I guess you want injectivity of the continuous map? Even with that, it's not clear how this answers the question: that $f$ is injective when restricted to the points $\{x_i\}$ does not mean that $f$ itself is injective.

Comment: Also, of course one cannot have $f(x_i) = i$ by compactness, but there are definitely cases where one can find continuous map so that $\{f(x_i)\}$ are all distinct.

Comment: @Didier I'm sorry. I forgot the word “injective”. It's done now.

Comment: Clearly wrong because even the circle can map into the reals and separate any finite number of points in the image. Of course any real map from the circle will not be injective, which is why your statement breaks down.

Comment: @DanRust What I wrote proves that there is no continuous map from $S^1$ into $\Bbb R$ which separates the points.

Comment: Just take a simple example: $X = S^1$ and $p_n = (1/n, \sqrt {1-n^{-2}})$. Then $f(x, y) = x$ is continuous and $f(p_n) = 1/n$ are all distinct.

Comment: The op said nothing about the function needing to be injective...

Comment: @DanRust How can a function which separates any two points fail to be injective?

Comment: The op isn't asking for it to be *every* pair of points, but just some predetermined (but arbitrary) subset of points.

Comment: That is, the op is asking if the set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\mid x_i\in X\}$ can be separated by a continuous function as long as X is compact Hausdorff

Comment: @DanRust That part of the question is answered by my reference to Urysohn's lemma (which had already been done by Artic Char in the comments). My answer concerns is about the “infinitely many points” part of the question.

Comment: It seems a bit of a leap to assume "infinitely many points" means *any* infinite subset. I would first assume that meant 'countably infinite' for which it is a good question. You are right though that if you want it for *any* infinite subset, then the entire space $X$ is itself such a subset. I guess it comes down to our interpretations of the OP's (admittedly ambiguous asked) question.

Answer (score 2):

For a finite set of points, this follows from the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) because compact Hausdorff spaces are normal, in a Hausdorff space, any finite set of points forms a closed subset, and all functions from a discrete set (finite set of points in a Hausdorff space) are continuous. (You can also use Urysohn's lemma and induction to get this)

That is, for your finite subset $A = \{x_1 \ldots, x_n \mid x_i \in X\}$, let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x_i) = i$. Then the Tietze extension theorem says there exists a continuous function $\tilde{f} \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{f}(x_i) = f(x_i)$.

For infinite (say countable) subsets, I believe the statement of the result breaks down in full generality because you can't guarantee the set $A$ is closed, though I can't think of a countable counterexample at the moment.

Comment: In the countable case, $f(x_i) = i$ for all $i$ is not possible since $f$ has to be bounded.

Comment: Yes, I explicitly said this argument only works for finite $A$. The countable case might be rather subtle, as it's not unreasonable to expect every countable subset of (say) $S^1$ can be separated by a real function. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I mean, if the OP's question is: given a countably infinite subset $\{x_i\}$ of $X$, can we find $f$ such that $f(x_i) = i$? Then the answer is no, instead of not sure.

Comment: Right, but I feel that parenthetical from the OP was just poorly thought through and not important.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. To be honest, now that the OP has accepted another answer, I am not really sure what kind of question the OP has in mind.